How to import/use CSV file data on Flutter app? Or is there an easier way to import/use data?
I'm still a newbie when it comes to Flutter (or mobile development) and would like to get some advice from veterans here.
I have a spreadsheet of data (2-3 columns, basically barcode-price combinations) and I want to import it into the app (to be used in auto calculating sale prices). There will be additions and modifications on this list by the time, so I thought a way where we can import CSV files so the app can process the data accordingly.
Is there a better/easier alternatives to import/update the database (ideally one that is customisable by user)? Or how can I implement this import CSV feature to the app? Tutorial or documentation about this would be nice.
I tried implementing the import CSV file feature to the app but I couldn't find enough or complete tutorial/documentation about how I could achieve this.
Basically my plan was:
The user opens the app, then selects/imports a CSV file from app settings (app will save it till there is a replacement file), then the app will use the data from CSV file for calculations.
